# Navigation controllers toolbar goes blank after showing a UIActionSheet from it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In an iOS run on iOS 6.1 (emulated) and 6.1.3 (physical device) application we show an UIActionSheet from a view with the following code:

```
  UIActionSheet *actionCreateNewComment = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:CLocalised(@"EditExistingComment") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:CLocalised(@"No") destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: CLocalised(@"Yes"), nil];
[actionCreateNewComment setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];
[actionCreateNewComment setTag:ActionSheetTagNewComment];
[actionCreateNewComment showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
[actionCreateNewComment release];
```

The View sets the toolbar with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:control];
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item]];
```

Where `control` is an `UISegmentedControl`.

The code for handling the button actions are:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    bool shouldAddNewComment = buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex];
    [self navigateToCommentScreen:shouldAddNewComment];
}
```

Every time this action sheet is shown the tool bar will go "blank". Not only for this view but also for the other views.

Here is an example of a work flow:
[image: Flowbetween Views]

Note that if I navigate from Instr to Comment without the UIActionSheet, but otherwise the same code, the problem will not appear.

The problem here is that in the "Instr" view the toolbar is empty.
If I pop two more views to return to "List" its toolbar will be empty as well:

[image: ListEmpytToolbar]

Even if I then navigate back to WO and Instr, by allocing and init new forms, and then pushing them, the toolbars will still be empty.

There is another navigation option from the "List" View that shows a "Summary" view. Depending on the data this view will show with or without buttons in the toolbar:
[image: Stats of summary view]

Both "Summary Button" and "Summary empty" are intended views. "Summary hidden" is shown after the UIActionSheet have been shown before navigating between Inst and Comment.
But if I navigate to a "Summary" view that is shown as "Summary Empty" in the picture (intended, due to the data) then the toolbar will start working everywhere again. Or at least until I show the UIActionSheet from the Instr view again.

There are some, in my opinion, strange things about this:

- If I navigate to a view where the toolbar is empty, which hides the toolbar, see pic: "SummaryEmpty", then the toolbar will show as intended in the other views.
- We use the same code to show an action sheet in other views of the application without any problem
- If I run the application on an emulated iOS 5.1 or emulated iOS 5.0 the problem does not appear

Have I missed something when it comes to dismissing the action sheet or how to show it?

Please let me know if you want more information.

Update:
If I forcibly call `[self setToolbarItems:nil]` after the action sheet button event and then update it with the same items as before the Tool bar will show up as intended.
This does not feel as the right way to do it.

Update 2013-05-28:
Thanks to @LOP_Luke I found out that if I do not navigate to the "Comment" view from `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` but just returned the tool bar will start working again. 
So, can there be some kind of problem when I navigate to another view when then `clickedButtonAtIndex` is still on the call stack?

**Update 2013-05-29**:
If I add a method:

```
-(void)commentScreenYes{
  [self vanigateToCommentScreen:YES];
}
```

And change the button code to:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    bool shouldAddNewComment = buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex];
    if(shouldAddNewComment){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(commentScreenYes) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    [self navigateToCommentScreen:shouldAddNewComment];
}
```

Then it will work for the cancel button, but not for the yes button. The cancel button will also make the toolbar work again after it have been "broken" by the yes button. If I pipe both buttons through this flow (by adding a new method) they will both work.
And still, if I run it at iOs 5.1 it will work no matter which flow I choose.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots? It's difficult to understand your view hierarchy just the question.

Comment: @Sulthan Will try to get some before the weekend, else at the start of next week.

Comment: @Sulthan added some screenshots, please let me know if you want some more clarifications.

Comment: What did you put in the `-viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: @marzapower They all contain `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`. Most of them also contain a `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:[self.toolbarItems count] ==0]`. All initialization of the toolbar is done in the `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Try moving that initialization in the `viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 2):

The `– setToolbarItems` method is a UIViewController method specific to each child view controller of your navigation controller. Assuming `[self navigateToCommentScreen:shouldAddNewComment]` pushes a new view controller onto the navigation stack you will have to set the toolbar items for the new view controller too as a separate call, regardless of what the action sheet is doing. For example,

```
-(void) navigateToCommentScreen:(bool) shouldAddComment{
    CommentViewController* viewController = [[CommentViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    [viewController setToolbarItems:self.toolbarItems];
}
```

Otherwise the new view controller will have no toolbar items and the toolbar will be blank.

**Edit**

I created a navigation controller with a root view controller that has a toolbar with a UISegmented control. I pushed a new view controller onto the navigation stack via a UIActionSheet delegate method and then popped it back. The toolbar was exactly how it should be on the root view controller (the segmented control faded back in as expected). You must be doing something more complicated  with your controller with regards to setting the toolbar items that is causing them to disappear. Without seeing your viewController's source methods it's hard to tell what the problem is. Make sure that you are not setting your toolbar items to nil or resetting them with an empty array somehow.

Comment: You are correct, but that is not the problem here. There are other places where [self navigateToCommentScreen:shouldAddNewComment]; gets called that does not cause this problem. It is only after the action sheet have been shown that the problem arise. The problem is even then when I pop ViewControllers from the navigationController. These forms calls setToolbarItems in their different viewDidLoad.

Comment: So what is the expected behavior? If you show an action sheet from a navigation controller's toolbar, the toolbar will be covered by the action sheet. Is that what you're saying the problem is? Because I don't think there's a way to show the action sheet from the top of the toolbar (having the toolbar remain visible under the action sheet). Also, viewDidLoad is not called when you pop a view controller from the navigation stack. If you need to change the toolbar items of the underlying view controller when you pop from the stack, those changes should be in viewWillAppear, not viewDidLoad.

Comment: I've added more info to the question. I think I've answered all your questions there. Otherwise, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the extended help! When I debug at `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` I can inspect, at the console with `po [self.toolbarItems count]`, and see that the count is 1, so it should not have been set to nil. I've also updated the question with (another) way to start up the toolbar again, by setting the toolbarItems to nil and then to their correct values at the `-viewWillAppear`. I've also search the entire project for any `setToolbarItems` in order to find any where it should be nil, but I can't find any.

Comment: Interesting, so `[self.toolbarItems count]` returns 1 after you pop  to Instr but you don't see anything on the toolbar? Also, what happens when you press "no" on the action sheet to cancel editing the comment? Does the toolbar still disappear?

Comment: Yes, the `[self.toolbarItems count]` returns one after I've pop back to Instr. Checked both in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. I even tagged up my toolbarItem to make sure it was the same one (it was). But you caught one interesting thing, if I cancel the `UIActionSheet` with the cancel button the tool bar shows  its element. That is even a way to "bring it back from the dead". Added this to the question.

Comment: So your problem seems unrelated to the action sheet and is more about the toolbar's visibility. In the above comment you say you call `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:[self.toolbarItems count] ==0]`. What if you just call `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]`? If that fixes the issue that probably means there is an ordering problem for when you're adding the items to the array and when you're setting the toolbar's visibility. In other words, the way you're setting the toolbar up, you need to make sure to add the items to the array **BEFORE** you set it's visibility.

Comment: I'm not ready to leave the action sheet out of the question. Here ar the main reasons:
I use the exact same code for the "no" button as I do when the sheet is not shown.
The navigationController is not really hidden, it's only "empty", or rather - isn't really drawn.
I've also found out that it works if I pipe the call through "performSelectorOnMainThread", updated the question with the code.